# How to highlight target column in hidden row in a table?

Tags: excel, vba, row, highlight

The following code works to highlight the target row and column in two tables `ListObject(1)` and `ListObject(2)` while clearing all hidden rows (Note: `ListObject(1)` is directly above `ListObject(2)`)

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim oList1 As ListObject
    Dim oList2 As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range

    Set oList1 = Me.ListObjects(1)

    ' Contains hidden rows when filter is applied
    Set oList2 = Me.ListObjects(2)

    ' Only proceed if `Target` is inside the table body
    If Intersect(Target, oList2.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Clear the color of all cells
    Me.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

    ' Highlights columns
    Set rng = Intersect(Target.EntireColumn, oList1.DataBodyRange)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 24
    End If

    ' Highlights columns
    Set rng = Intersect(Target.EntireColumn, oList2.DataBodyRange)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 24

    ' Highlights rows
    Set rng = Intersect(Target.EntireRow, oList2.DataBodyRange)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 38

    ' Clears all hidden rows
    For Each oRow In oList2.ListRows
        If oRow.Range.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            oRow.Range.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
        
    Next oRow

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Question:** How do I highlight target column in hidden row on `ListObject(2)`?

EDIT1:

Tried to highlight hidden target column after clearing hidden rows. But I get a `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`

```
    Dim oCol As ListColumn

    ' Clear hidden row and recolor hidden target column
    For Each oRow In oList2.ListRows
        If oRow.Range.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            With Target
                oCol.Range.Interior.ColorIndex = 24
            End With
        End If
        
    Next oRow
```

Comment: So `oRow.Range.Interior.ColorIndex = 0` clears the hidden row coloring, but you want to preserve the color just for the column in question?

Comment: Yes sir.  If I change the target after rows are hidden, the columns in those rows remain clear.  I want to maintain the color of the target column in the hidden rows.

Comment: You can either recolor the target column after clearing the row, or you can clear everything except the target column.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `Set rng = Intersect(Target.EntireColumn, oList2.DataBodyRange)`, `rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 24` a second time? ... or do it after clearing the hidden rows?

Comment: I tried that before but that won't highlight the hidden columns

Comment: Very interesting. In a normal range, one can apply color to hidden rows (either hidden manually or filtered out), but for some reason in a table this isn't happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "reapply" the color formatting to the column(s) in the hidden row(s):

```
    ' Clears all hidden rows
    Dim oRow As ListRow
    For Each oRow In oList2.ListRows
        If oRow.Range.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            oRow.Range.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

            ' Reapply the color to the columns
            Intersect(oRow.Range, Target.EntireColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
        End If
    Next
```